# Cannot convert argument 1 from " unsigned int *" to "size t *"

Tags: c++

I am working on Student Project and got SDK from site and building libraries on Visual Studio. Once I build libraries using cmake opened solution in VS and build in VS gives me above error. Not sure how to fix it.

This is proc where I get error.

```
pmdDllExport int pmdpGetSourceDataDescription (unsigned hnd, PMDDataDescription *result)
{
    if (!idOk (hnd))
    {
        globalErrorMessage = "unknown handle";
        return PMD_UNKNOWN_HANDLE;
    }

    SrcPluginData *dat = g_data[hnd];

    int c_channels = 1;
    //
    dat->currentDD.type = PMD_USER_DEFINED_0; /* USER DEFINE TYPE DATA for O3D3xx data*/
    dat->currentDD.subHeaderType = PMD_IMAGE_DATA;
    dat->currentDD.img.numSubImages = 6;/* Mentions number of images in image data
                                        buffer. We have six images*/

    ...

    /* Get Size of image data buffer */
    **dat->o3d3xxCamera->getFrameDataSize (& (dat->currentDD.size));**

    dat->currentDD.PID = hnd;
    dat->currentDD.DID = g_did;

    /*Output this descriptor to calling function */
    memcpy (result , &dat->currentDD, sizeof (PMDDataDescription));

    return PMD_OK;
}
```

When I checked what is `o3d3xxCamera->getFrameDataSize` defined as it is defined as

```
int32_t getFrameDataSize (size_t *dataSize);
```

I looked at many queries and they say better to pass variable as type `size_t` When I checked what is `dat->currentdd` its struct. So I am not sure how to change this type to `size_t`.

```
/**<local datadescriptor of the current data */
PMDDataDescription currentDD;

struct PMDDataDescription
{
  unsigned PID;
  unsigned DID;
  unsigned type;
  unsigned size;

  unsigned subHeaderType;
  ...
```

Comment: If you're running on a 64-bit platform, then `sizeof(unsigned int) <= 4 < 8 == sizeof(size_t)`.

Answer (score 2):

**Do not** be tempted to just `reintepret_cast` the pointer!  That will not do what you want, unless `size_t` happens to be the same as `unsigned int`, which varies from platform to platform.

Instead, you'll want to use a temporary, and copy back when you're done:

```
size_t size = dat->currentDD.size;   // this will promote as necessary
dat->o3d3xxCamera->getFrameDataSize(&size);
dat->currentDD.size = size;          // write it back
```

One or other of the assignments may need a `static_cast`, if `sizeof (size_t)` differs from `sizeof (unsigned int)`.  This is fine, as it will be value-preserving (assuming that the value is representable in both types).

Answer (score 1):

If the types have different sizes, you can't reliably cast!

The receiver will treat the pointer as a pointer to a variable with a different size from what you actually have, and there will be breakage (undefined behavior).

Simply change the structure to have

```
size_t size;
```

If you can't change the structure, then of course you can use a temporary for the call, then cast that value into the struct. That will work, assuming you never *need* the higher precision of `size_t` of course.

Comment: If you're not in a position to modify the struct, see my answer for a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
dat->o3d3xxCamera->getFrameDataSize (& (dat->currentDD.size));
```

This passes the address of `dat->currentDD.size` as parameter to the `getFrameDataSize()` function.

```
PMDDataDescription currentDD;

struct PMDDataDescription
{
  unsigned PID;
  unsigned DID;
  unsigned type;
  unsigned size;
```

`currentDD.size` is of type `unsigned`.

```
int32_t getFrameDataSize (size_t *dataSize);
```

The function expects the addess of a `size_t`.

> Cannot convert argument 1 from " unsigned int *" to "size t *"

Apparently on your system `size_t` is `typedef`'ed to something different than `unsigned int`, making the two pointers incompatible. This might happen on 64-bit systems, where `int` is 32bit, but `size_t` is 64bit.

The **easy** fix is to simply cast the type (1):

```
dat->o3d3xxCamera->getFrameDataSize(& ( static_cast< size_t >(dat->currentDD.size) ) );
```

The Right Thing (tm) would probably (2) be to refactor `PMDDataDescription` to use `size_t` for its `size` member.

---

(1): I say it's easy, not that it's correct. I have no idea what `PMDDataDescription` is, what library it might come from, or what it is used for. I do not know what `getFrameDataSize()` *does* with its parameter. If it does pointer arithmetics on it, casting will break your application, and there is virtually nothing you can do about it because the two API's involved apparently to not agree on data types. We're looking at a very fragile setup here.

(2): You might not have control over its sources. You might be looking at something that is part of a *specified* API, i.e. cannot be changed for practical reasons. I'm just sayin' that **properly constructed software shouldn't have run into this problem in the first place**.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast pointers. You should try instead to cast only 'unsigned char' into 'size_t', not 'unsigned char*' and 'size_t*'